# What's the significance of different laser weapon types?

Tags: weapons, starfinder

What is up with all the different types of laser weapons? There's Zenith, Parallax, Corona, and others, but I can't seem to find the significance of these subtypes of laser. I am assuming there are maybe certain armors or something that resist say a zenith laser, but not a corona laser?

Using Ctrl+F doesn't seem to be picking up any relevant info in my PDF. The index is of equal uselessness.

Any help on determining what all these types mean and what I should be looking for in arming myself with a laser weapon would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about the entries in the [weapons](https://www.starjammersrd.com/equipment/weapons/) tables for Small Arms and Longarms - under Laser Pistol (Aphelion, Azimuth, Corona, Parallax, Perihelion, Zenith), Laser Rifle (Aphelion, Azimuth, Corona, Parallax, Perihelion, Zenith), and Artillery Laser (Aphelion, Azimuth, Corona, Parallax, Perihelion, Zenith)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The terms you're looking at differentiate item level.

[Item Level](https://www.aonsrd.com/Equipment.aspx)

> ...  represents the scarcity and value of the technology and/or magic employed in its construction- higher­ level items generally incorporate more advanced technology
> or mystical forces.

Zenith is *the* level 17 laser pistol (meaning it "should" only become available around level 16, see below) and Zenith is *the* level 20 laser rifle.

In a sense, azimuth are the weakest laser technology, increasing to corona, aphelion, perihelion, parallax, and finally zenith. However, you generally cannot get items far above your level.

Notably,

> While characters can utilize items of any level, Game Masters should keep in mind that allowing characters access to items far above their current level may imbalance the game. [...]
>
> Rather than meticulously track every arms dealer, contact, guild, and license a character has access to, the game assumes that **in typical settlements you can find and purchase anything with an item level no greater than your character level + 1, and at major settlements items up to your character level + 2.** The GM can restrict access to some items (even those of an appropriate level) or make items of a higher level available for purchase (possibly at a greatly increased price or in return for a favor done for the seller).

---

Trivia: [azimuth](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/azimuth?s=t), [corona](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/corona?s=t), [aphelion](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aphelion?s=t), [perihelion](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/perihelion?s=t), [parallax](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/parallax?s=t), and [zenith](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/zenith?s=t) are all astronomical terms relating to angles or viewing angles (and generally have nothing to do with lasers).

Comment: After i posted this, i saw the item level thing and kind of figgured this was the case... but i have been at this character creation thing for nearly 6 hours, as today is the first day i've even opened the book. lots of info to process and I guess I just thought there was more to it than simple power level.